# Unable to call Elastic beanstalk APIs via amplify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS. I have my node/express.js backend hosted on the Elastic beanstalk and it's working as per expectation. The express.js APIs communicate with the AWS RDS MySql database and send response accordingly. I have integrated the APIs calls in the React frontend and it is working fine locally. Now I have deployed the React frontend on the amplify and React app is hosted there now. But the API calls to elastic beanstalk are failing on the Amplify with the response "TypeError: Failed to fetch". I have also analyzed the Elastic beanstalk logs but could not find anything there. I wanna know why API calls are working perfectly locally but not on the amplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that Elastic Beanstalk requires that the communnication protocol has to be the same for both sender and receiver. So, the solution is to use either HTTP or HTTPS for both Front-End and Back-End.